# How to assign values to slices in Scipy sparse huge matrix

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

- I have Huge matrix called Mat_A, when I tried to slice it and assign values, I had got the following Error:

  - `Mat_A[:,0 ] = np.ravel(Mat_A.sum(axis=0)) TypeError: coo_matrix' object does not support item assignment`
- How can I assign values in the same spirit to the dense matrix`weights` befor going to sparse space?

[image: Mat_A]

```
Mat_A = sparse.coo_matrix((weights, (i_indices_O, j_indices_O)), shape=(pixel_nb_O, pixel_nb_O))
Mat_A[:,0 ] = np.ravel(Mat_A.sum(axis=0))
Mat_A[:,1:] = 0
Mat_A = Mat_A.tocsr()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`coo_matrix`'s sparse format comes with some disadvantages, which are well mentioned in the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.13.0/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.coo_matrix.html):

> does not directly support:
>
> - arithmetic operations
> - **slicing**

`COO` is a fast format for constructing sparse matrices, though for arithmetic operations you should switch to `CSR` or `CSC`.